# Using values in a cookie to amend page content - Google Tag Manager

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

I have a cookie that stores values (delimited by |) when someone visits certain pages on my site i.e:

Product|50|UK

I want to use a Custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager to amend content on another page using values from the cookie.

I.e. I have a `<h2>Old Title</h2>` that I want to amend to `<h2>Title</h2>` where 'Title' is the value of the first delimited string in my cookie.

I understand I probably need to use jQuery to select the correct element on the page; but how to I rewrite this with a value from a cookie?

Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: If you do not already have jQuery in use, you should not include it. It's easily possible w/o.

Comment: Using Google Tag Manager? I do not have access to the hard code on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully tested the following code on my site. Be aware that this code writes the cookie value into the **first** h2 element. Since i don't know what your site looks like, that might be subject of change.

You have to put this Code into a custom HTML Tag. You also have to add the trigger "DOM Ready" in Google Tag Manager, to make sure the element is available.

```
<script>
// extract the cookieValue
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var cookieValue = getCookie("nameOfYourCookie");
var cookieSplit = cookieValue.split("|")[0];

// Write the Cookie-Value into the first h2 Element
function changeTitle(){  
  document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML = cookieSplit; 
}
changeTitle();
</script>
```